# Bad Resquest in RestSharp, but working on Postman

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

Basically, I've been trying to authenticate through oauth2 on c# using restsharp, but I am receiving a bad request response, I'm not sure if it's something related to the API configuration or if it's something I'm missing In my code.

```
public string getToken(string email, string password)
    {
        var restclient = new RestClient(loginUrl);
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("request/oauth") { Method = Method.GET };
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("email", HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(email));
        request.AddParameter("password", HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(password));
        request.AddParameter("grant_type", HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode("password"));
        var tResponse = restclient.Execute(request);
        var responseJson = tResponse.Content;
        string token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson)["access_token"].ToString();
        return token;
    }
```

this is the response when I execute that code
[image: restsharp execution]
[image]

An this is the postman execution

[image: Postman execution]

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode` calls and call https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/67aae8c0f5dfd4415bc67471327faca148c2c56c/docs/api/RestSharp.md#method-addqueryparameterstring-string-boolean with `encode` as `true` instead?

Comment: Actually, my first try was without HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode I just added to try if it was that

Comment: var restclient = new RestClient(loginUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.AddParameter("email", email);
            request.AddParameter("password", password);
            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
            var tResponse = restclient.Execute(request);

Comment: `var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.AddQueryParameter("email", email, true);
            request.AddQueryParameter("password", password, true);
            request.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", "password", true);
            var tResponse = restclient.Execute(request);`

Comment: Keeps receiving bad request, tried with encode set as true and false..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there problem with adding parameters the way you are adding.
latest restsharp support this,

Also,avoid encoding of params by setting to `false`

```
var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
request.AddQueryParameter("email", "test@test.com",false);
```

Comment: Are you passing client id and client secret in your header in postman request. Please check

Comment: In postman I'm just passing the email, password, and grant_type which is the password and email, not client id and client secret.

Comment: As per above comments, try avoid encoding.

Answer (score 0):

var restclient = new RestClient(loginUrl); I think you need to check your url.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. you OAuth is password grantype are your sure your not missing any credentials like **client_id, scope  and client_secret**.

```
public static string getAccessToken(string usern, string pswd)
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenUrl"]);
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest() { Method = Method.GET};

            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            request.AddParameter("username", usern, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            request.AddParameter("password", pswd, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
           

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            var responseJson = response.Content;
            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(responseJson)["access_token"].ToString();


            return token;

        }
```